# Index/Sumproduct calculation error

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have been working on an excel problem for the better part of 24 hours. I have a formula that almost does what I want but it is not returning what I imagine it should return:

```
=INDEX(Data!D:D,SUMPRODUCT((Data!C:C=Total!A5)*(Data!A:A="Total")*(Data!B:B="Total")*(ROW(Data!D:D))))
```

I imagine the row to index column D in the Data! worksheet to be the actual row in which the match occurs, but FOR EVERY VALUE BUT THE FIRST VALUE, the value returned comes from 3 rows below it.

Yes, so for the first cell in which I apply that formula, I get back the right value from Column D of Data!. But, for every subsequent cell with the formula, I'm getting back the value in Column D of Data! 3 rows below the match.

I've tried every combination of subtracting 3 from the formula (to return the proper row), but to no avail. Still that wouldn't explain why the first cell in which the formula is applied returns the expected value!

Any and all help is much appreciated, of course...

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question yesterday?

Comment: @Excellll I was attempting to use the index/match function - here I am having trouble with the index/sum product function

Comment: I'm not sure why this doesn't work but I would still use MATCH as suggested in your other question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26631625/sumproduct-return-a-row-number/26632300#26632300. `INDEX/MATCH` is more appropriate if you are looking up a single value

Comment: Using `SUMPRODUCT` for the row number instead of `MATCH` will only work if the look up value is unique. It does not return the first match, it returns the sum total of all matches. Take a screenshot of some redacted data and post a link to it if you cannot provide some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not entirely clear to me whether you want to find the *first, second, etc* matches to Total!A5 or if you are trying to find the first match to A5 then the first match to A6, etc. This proposed solution is for the former.

I prefer using the method of mathematical exclusion for catching multiple returns on matches. If you eliminate what doesn't match, then what remains must be the set of matching results. I'm also impatient enough that I find the calculation lag of full column references with `SUMPRODUCT` annoying so I've chopped down your range references to the first ~1K rows.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!$D$2:$D$999, SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$998)+((Data!$C$2:$C$999<>Total!$A$5)+(Data!$A$2:$A$999<>"Total")+(Data!$B$2:$B$999<>"Total"))*1E+99,,),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

This is a standard (*non-array*) formula. Fill down as necessary to catch all matching returns. When you  transcribe this for your own purposes, remember that `ROW(1:998)` is the *position within* `Data!D2:D999`, not the actual row number on the worksheet. `ROW(1:1)` is simply a counter that increments as you fill down. Sometimes a `COUNTIF` is more appropriate there and can be used to catch multiple matching returns on multiple lookup values.